# What is the equivalence symbol between two objects?

Tags: soft-question, equivalence-relations

I'm working on a pedagogical presentation in which I start by saying that two apples are *equivalent* things but not the *same* things. Therefore, my first slide is made of two distinct apples with the equivalence symbol between the two. Which one is appropriate and mathematically right ? This presentation is part of a research grant application and will be presented to a jury of mathematicians, so a bad choice of the symbol on the first slide could be heavily blamed on me.

Should I use $\simeq$, $\equiv$, $\leftrightarrow$ or ~ ? Or something else?

Comment: I suggest using $\sim$ and explaining what $\sim$ means. Explaining the symbol is the important part here, the actual symbol doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I grew up with $\equiv$ for generic equivalence and $\simeq$ for isomorphism of spaces (so maybe don't use $\simeq$). $\sim$ is also fine. Definitely don't use $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: $\equiv$ and $\sim$ both have no chance of being perceived as wrong by anyone